# What is the easiest way to setup leaderboard and achievements in unity?

Tags: unity

How do you guys setup leaderboard and achievements in your game.
I have finished my game and want to add these stuff on both android and app store.
What's the easiest way to go about it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added play games services plugin in unity and It worked fine on my previous project as it was only for android but I also want this to work on IOS so there must be a way to do it on both sides easily. I found this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-SocialAPI.html but I dont know what to do.

Comment: You might want to refine your question and ask us more details about that approach instead e.g. what part is unclear, etc.

Comment: [galaxysdk.com](https://galaxysdk.com) might be worth looking at - they do leaderboards, achievements, clans, etc